# Error "Unbound value" when trying to define a type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I try to define this type :

```
type 'a operation = {
operande_1 : 'a;
operande_2 : 'a;
func : ('a -> 'a -> 'a) * string;
result : 'a;
};;
```

But when I try to initalize something of this type that way :

```
let o = {
operande_1 = 1.0;
operande_2 = 2.3;
func = ((+.), "+");
result = (fst func) operande_1 operande_2};;
```

I get the error "`Unbound value func`" at the line `result = (fst func) operande_1 operande_2}`

Well it is defined just before so I don't really get what's wrong... Could somebody help to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func` is a field of record that is not yet defined. So, to access it you need first of all the value representing a record. Moreover, the syntax to access the record field is `<record> . <field>`.

The proper code would be something like this:

```
let o = 
  let func = ((+.), "+") in
  let operande_1 = 1.0 in
  let operande_2 = 2.3 in
  {
    operande_1;
    operande_2;
    func;
    result = (fst func) operande_1 operande_2
  }
```